# using terraform cloud with the google provider on github actions gives an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, workflow, github-actions

I'm trying to use terraform cloud with gcp.  To that end I have the following provider configuation

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.89.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  region  = local.region
  project = local.project
  credentials = 
}
```

As per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#credentials-1, I have created the environment variable `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` and set the credential file that gets downloaded.

Now when I try to run the workflow using github actions I get the following error

[image]

This is what my gihub workflow file looks like

```
name: 'event profile api deploy pipeline'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform-deploy'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Install the latest version of Terraform CLI and configure the Terraform CLI configuration file with a Terraform Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

    # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terraform Init
      working-directory: ./terraform
      run: terraform init

    # Checks that all Terraform configuration files adhere to a canonical format
    - name: Terraform Format
      working-directory: ./terraform
      run: terraform fmt -check

    # Generates an execution plan for Terraform
    - name: Terraform Plan
      working-directory: ./terraform
      run: terraform plan
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here ?

Comment: You say you're creating an (incorrectly named) environment variable for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` but I don't see it in your workflow. ADC and thus tf expect that variable in the environment.

Comment: This looks useful: https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth The new Workload Identity Federation is neat!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had not used the `backend` portion in the `provider` sections.  Given below is the working provider version with Terraform cloud

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.89.0"
    }
  }
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "org"

    workspaces {
      name = "namespace"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  region  = local.region
  project = local.project
}
```